# in this i had 2 tables i need oldvalues in one row and newvalues in one row

Tags: mysql

**Table1**

> create table emp(id int,emp_id int,
>       name varchar(30),email varchar(50),mobile_no int,comments varchar(50));

**table2**

> create table history(id int,oldvalue varchar(50),newvalue
>   varchar(50));

**inserting into 1st table**

```
insert into emp(emp_id,name,email,mobile_no,comments) 
 values(1, 'gobi','gobinath@gmail.com',9944,'good');
```

TRIGGER

> CREATE TRIGGER tri
>
> ```
> BEFORE UPDATE ON emp
>
> FOR EACH ROW 
>
> BEGIN
>
>     INSERT INTO history
>
>     SET id = '1',
>      oldvalue = OLD.name,
>      newvalue = NEW.name;
>      INSERT INTO history
>
>      SET id = '2',
>       oldvalue = OLD.email,
>      newvalue = NEW.email;
>      INSERT INTO history
>
>      SET id = '3',
>      oldvalue = OLD.mobile_no,
>      newvalue = NEW.mobile_no;
>         END;
> ```

```
UPDATE emp 

SET 
    name = 'ashok',
 email = 'ashok@gmail.com',
mobile_no = '929292'
WHERE
    emp_id = 1;
```

**This above trigger is working fine but i need to fill in 2 rows, but output of this trigger is multiple rows creating.**

Comment: As you had made changes in all three field ,then obviously it will make three entry for `old value` and `new value`.

Comment: Yeah i understand but i need OLD.name,OLD.email,OLD.mobile_no in one row under oldvalue  and NEW.name,NEW.email,NEW.mobile_no in one row under newvalue column. pls help me...

Comment: you can simply create `history` table with same column as in `emp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table emp(id int auto_increment,emp_id int,
name varchar(30),email varchar(50),mobile_no int,comments varchar(50),primary key(id));

create table history(id int,oldvalue varchar(50),newvalue varchar(50));




insert into emp(emp_id,name,email,mobile_no,comments) 
 values(1, 'gobi','gobinath@gmail.com',9944,'good');



CREATE TRIGGER tri 
    AFTER UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE ooldvalue TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE nnewvalue TEXT DEFAULT '';

IF((OLD.name!=NEW.name) OR (OLD.email!=NEW.email) OR (OLD.mobile_no!=NEW.mobile_no))THEN
SET ooldvalue = CONCAT(ooldvalue,'id=', OLD.id,','); 

    END IF;

IF(OLD.name!=NEW.name) THEN 
        SET ooldvalue=CONCAT(ooldvalue,'name=',OLD.name,',');
        SET nnewvalue = CONCAT(nnewvalue,'name=',NEW.name,',');
    END IF;

IF(OLD.email!=NEW.email) THEN 
        SET ooldvalue=CONCAT(ooldvalue,'email=',OLD.email,',');
        SET nnewvalue = CONCAT(nnewvalue,'email=',NEW.email,',');
    END IF;

IF(OLD.mobile_no!=NEW.mobile_no) THEN 
        SET ooldvalue=CONCAT(ooldvalue,'mobile_no=',OLD.mobile_no,',');
        SET nnewvalue = CONCAT(nnewvalue,'mobile_no=',NEW.mobile_no,',');
    END IF;

IF(ooldvalue!='' AND nnewvalue!='') THEN

        IF(ooldvalue!=nnewvalue)THEN
            SET ooldvalue = SUBSTRING(ooldvalue,1,CHAR_LENGTH(ooldvalue)-1);
            SET nnewvalue = SUBSTRING(nnewvalue,1,CHAR_LENGTH(nnewvalue)-1);
            INSERT INTO history(oldvalue,newvalue) values (ooldvalue,nnewvalue);
         END IF; 
        END IF;
      END;
```

select  * from emp

select  * from history

```
UPDATE emp 
SET 
    name = 'ashok', email = 'ashok@gmail.com',mobile_no = '929292'
where
    emp_id = 1;
```